# Exported application from Processing fails to read serial port

Tags: processing

I am building a processing app which reads the serial port using:

```java
setup(){
    myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[5], 9600);
}

draw(){
    while (myPort.available() > 0) {
        int inByte = myPort.read();
        // my code here
    }
}
```

This works perfectly while testing from Processing. When exporting as a mac application, the whole thing crashes and burns as soon as actual input is received from the serial port.
(the app runs fine, but when I press my Arduino button, it crashes).

Comment: Please post a log of the crash. One option is to open the Console app(Applications/Utilities/Console) and filter your Processing app, another is opening your Processing app from Terminal (e.g. /path/to/your/ProcessinSerial.app/Contents/MacOS/./JavaApplicationStub) and paste the output when you get a crash

Comment: I found out what caused the crash : the arduino board kept triggering a complex Processing function 30 times per second, crashing the app. For some reason this bug didn't show when testing straight from Processing itself, that's why I thought the error was caused by the exported app.

Comment: cool, glad that got sorted out.You can post the details as an answer to help others that might run into the same issue in the future